# RegEx to find inner content of [code] tags

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string value of something like this:

```
[code]
hi
[/code]
```

I can use this regex to get the tag and the middle content:

```
/(?:(\[code\]))([\s\S]*)(?:(\[\/code\]))/gi
```

But if I have a string value with multiple [code] tag sets then it returns as a single match instead of multiple:

```
[code]
hi
[/code]

[code]
hello
[/code]
```

I'm running the RegEx through a text.replace to parse the middle content something like:

```
text.replace(re, function(match, open_tag, middle, close_tag) {
    //do stuff here
    return open_tag + middle + close_tag;
});
```

But like I said, it's not being that there is two separate code sets, only as a single and that's likely my use of `\S` matching everything. How do I parse this properly?

quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rutsk28L/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a non-greedy variant:

```
/(?:(\[code\]))([\s\S]*?)(?:(\[\/code\]))/gi
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bD1iN8/2)

The ungreedy unifier `*?` unifies with zero or more, but the least possible.

You can furthermore probably omit the capturing of the `[code]` blocks in brackets:

```
/\[code\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/code\]/gi
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qP2cV0/1)

making the regex a bit shorter and more readable.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot!